# getElementsByClassName not working on parsed html data in greasemonkey

Tags: dom, parsing, greasemonkey

var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", linksRaw, false);
    xhReq.send(null);
    var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
    var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.innerHTML = serverResponse.replace(//g, '');
    var plzWork = tempDiv.getElementsByClassName('organizationID').innerHTML;
    console.log(plzWork);

The value of 'plzWork'  :-) which is logged to the firebug console is always 'undefined'  while the link code is

```
<a class="organisationID" href="orglists.htm">Partner Organisations</a>
```

I'm writing this script in the latest versions of Greasemonkey and FF 3.6

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I hate to point out the piddling little detail because I don't have any other idea why it wouldn't work, but do you really use "organizationID" with a Z when the classname has "organisationID" with an S?

Answer (score 1):

`tempDiv.getElementsByClassName('organizationID')`

returns a collection, not a single element.

`tempDiv.getElementsByClassName('organizationID').innerHtml`

then is illegal. Maybe you mean:

`tempDiv.getElementsByClassName('organizationID')[0].innerHtml`